# Passing 1 of 3 values to a Sub

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I want to update a single (1 of 3) variable in a `Sub`.

The 3 variables have already been assigned, but I would like to update one of the variables.

See script below for a simple example of passing `string`s between subs in different `Macros`

In Macro1

```
Sub Sub1()

Text1 = "First Text"
Text2 = "Second Text"
Text3 = "Third Text"

Call Macro2.Sub2(Text1, Text2, Text3)

End Sub
```

In Macro2

```
Public PassedText1, PassedText2, PassedText3 As String
Sub Sub2(ByVal r1 As String, ByVal r2 As String, ByVal r3 As String)

PassedText1 = r1
PassedText2 = r2
PassedText3 = r3

End Sub
'=======================
```

I know I can create another sub in `Macro2` where I can then pass a `string` and then assign it to the Public variable.

If there not another way?

I though of Something like:

```
Sub Sub3()

SomeText = "New Text"

Call Sub2(r1:=SomeText)

End Sub
```

Comment: Why not use Macro2  and send empty strings for values you do not want to change(or some odd characters e.g. '###')? You could then use `IF` statements in Macro2 to see which values need updating.Or use Optional in the Sub definitions!

Comment: Thanks @MiguelH, your proposal is similar to the answer by R3uK. with the If statement. However only having to Call a sub with single variable at various points seems to be more efficient to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you define your sub like this, you can use what you proposed :

```
Sub Sub2(Optional ByVal r1 As Variant, Optional ByVal r2 As Variant, Optional  ByVal r3 As Variant)
```

So, 2 changed things for each argument `Optional ByVal r1 As Variant` :

1. `Optional` speaks for itself
2. `As Variant` because you'll need to test is the argument is present in your call with the `IsMissing()` method, but for that the argument need to be defined as a Variant

So like this for the 3 arguments in your proc :

```
If Not IsMissing(r1) Then PassedText1 = r1
```

Comment: Glad I could help! ;) Enjoy SO!

Comment: If only in knew this 3 months ago. Hahahah

Comment: yeah, it is a classical for developers to feel that way and it only stop if you stop learning, so it is good sign! Bonne continuation! ;)