# pass multiple argument from one sub to another sub

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to pass multiple arguments from one sub to another sub, but it's not working. Even if I try to define variable as string.

```
Sub run
    Dim uniqueId, errorMessage, jobId, ErrorCode
    uniqueId = "abcc"
    jobId = "efgh"
    ErrorCode = "ijkl"
    errorMessage = "mnop"
    DisplayCustomError errorMessage, uniqueId, jobId, ErrorCode
End Sub

Sub DisplayCustomError(errorMessage, uniqueId, jobId, ErrorCode)
    WScript.Echo uniqueId
    WScript.Echo jobId
    WScript.Echo ErrorCode
    WScript.Echo errorMessage
End Sub
```

Comment: This does not appear to be related to Excel or Excel VBA

Comment: You need to actually invoke your `Run` procedure. Put a line with just the word `Run` at the end of your script. If that doesn't help: please explain in more detail how *exactly* the code is "not working".

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers In my code 1st I am getting error for Dim uniqueId As String that is "Microsoft VBScript compilation error: Expected end of statement" After that I am getting error for Sub DisplayCustomError(ByVal errorMessage As String) that Microsoft VBScript compilation error: Expected ')'

Comment: Your code doesn't have a type definition `As String`, and it would be invalid anyway. VBScript doesn't allow typed variables/parameters. The code you posted should work just fine if you simply invoke the `Run` procedure.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Then how can I pass multiple argument from one sub run to Sub DisplayCustomError()

Comment: Your. Code. Already. Does. That.

Answer (score 3):

`VBA` and `VBScript` are a bit different.

But for `VBA` the following code will work perfectly.

A few pointers:

- You always wants to `Dim` all your variables, I understand this is probably just a quick example you provided but I felt to mentioned it.
- When receiving variables in a `Sub` you always want to define them in the `Sub` which is receiving them as to make correct use of the `variable` in the proceeding code.
- Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33496517/passing-1-of-3-values-to-a-sub) for a question I asked about only passing certain `variables` to a `Sub`. This might help when you only want to pass one or two `variables` to a "receiving" `Sub`

  ```
  Option Explicit

  Sub run()

      Dim uniqueId As String
      Dim errorMessage As String
      Dim jobId As String
      Dim ErrorCode As String

      uniqueId = "abcc"
      jobId = "efgh"
      ErrorCode = "ijkl"
      errorMessage = "mnop"

      DisplayCustomError errorMessage, uniqueId, jobId, ErrorCode

  End Sub

  Sub DisplayCustomError(ByVal errorMessage As String, ByVal uniqueId As String, _
                         ByVal jobId As String, ByVal ErrorCode As String)

      Debug.Print uniqueId
      Debug.Print jobId
      Debug.Print ErrorCode
      Debug.Print errorMessage

  End Sub
  ```

Comment: I tried that also but 1st I am getting error for Dim uniqueId As String that is "Microsoft VBScript compilation error: Expected end of statement" After that I am getting error for Sub DisplayCustomError(ByVal errorMessage As String) that Microsoft VBScript compilation error: Expected ')'

Comment: @DevendraVastrakar `Dim uniqueId As String` is VBA code. VBScript interpreters don't understand VBA code. Stick to the VBScript code from your question and follow the advice I already gave you.

Answer (score -1):

It has to be `Call DisplayCustomError(...)` because its a sub, only functions are called withouth anything in front. 
Also:

```
Sub DisplayCustomError(ByVal errorMessage as String, ByVal uniqueId as String, ByVal jobId as String, ByVal ErrorCode as String)
```

Comment: That's plain nonsense. Of course you can invoke a Sub without the `Call` keyword. Also, typed parameters aren't required in VBA and aren't even allowed in VBScript.

Comment: @UGP : I tried that also but 1st I am getting error for Dim uniqueId As String that is "Microsoft VBScript compilation error: Expected end of statement" After that I am getting error for Sub DisplayCustomError() that Microsoft VBScript compilation error: Expected ')'

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers : I tried that also but 1st I am getting error for Dim uniqueId As String that is "Microsoft VBScript compilation error: Expected end of statement" After that I am getting error for Sub DisplayCustomError() that Microsoft VBScript compilation error: Expected ')'